# ASP.NET MVC Authentication using External Provider - Google/Facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am using Microsoft/Google/Facebook Authentication in my asp.net MVC application, which authenticates user & redirect users to my site. This works fine.

Issue : Anyone having a Microsoft/Google/Facebook account can able to sign in to my application. I should only allow users those who are registered/mapped in our database ie if a person purchased a licences only he should able to login using external provider.

Example : 
1) User1 has a Microsoft/Google account & user1 is a valid user in our database. So we can allow him to see the content from our site.
  2)  user2 has a microsoft/Google account, but he isn't valid user in our db. He shouldn't able to gain access to our site.

How can I achieve this in ASP.NET MVC. I am using client id & client secret key from external providers.

sample code from startup class

```
  app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
    {
    ClientId = "",
    ClientSecret = ""
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AccountController.cs (default code if you haven't changed it)

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }

        if(EmailNotRegistered(result.ExtraData["userid"]))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }

        var bresult = OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false);
        if (bresult)
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

       // etc...
    }
```

You will need to write the function `bool EmailNotRegistered(string email)` and do the logic where it checks the local database. There might be something already available in the Membership API to check but I don't know right now.

By the way, each provider is different so the ExtraData field might be "email" or something else - use the debugger to find out!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my AccountController

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

           // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                    return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Then you have your answer! `// If the user does not have an account` currently marks where you would normally allow the user to sign up for the local account. Change that to display a permission denied or whatever.